# Author can't see drafts when "sent back" from publisher in workbench

Tags: workbench

I have a problem after installing workbench access, workbench moderation.

When an author creates a blog entry and sets it to needs review, the publisher will receive it in his work bench.  When the publisher sets the blog entry back to draft, the author DOES NOT see it in his work bench.  If the author were given the link directly to the the blog entry, he can still end it.

How can the author access the draft content that's been sent back to him by using the workbench interface?

Comment: why the down vote?  I was also able to resolve the situation with a custom module as per answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The creators of workbench didn't accommodate the behaviour that I mentioned in my question.  Hence, we have to build a simple module to do this .  Here's the code I used from the

```
/**
 * Implements hook_node_update().
 */    
function mymodule_node_update($node) {
  db_update('node_revision')
    ->fields(array('uid' => $node->uid))
    ->condition('nid', $node->nid)
    ->condition('vid', $node->vid)
    ->execute();
}

/**
 * Implements hook_workbench_moderation_transition().
 */
function mymodule_workbench_moderation_transition($node, $previous_state, $new_state) {
  if (isset($node->nid) && isset($node->vid) && isset($node->uid)) {
    mymodule_node_update($node);
  }
}
```

I got the solution from an answer in this question here:

[Assigning revision owner when moderating backwards with Workbench](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/45114/assigning-revision-owner-when-moderating-backwards-with-workbench)